# IQueryable<T> Kind Of Object

Tags: c#, linq

What kind of object this line returns ? How can I see the metadata of it to see the inheritance and methods which has ?

```
IQueryable<Product> products = repository.Products
                        .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                        .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                        .Take(PageSize);
```

In debug mode I see it returns the following object:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product].OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Skip(3).Take(3)
```

Comment: Press F1 in visual studio?

Comment: With F1 I get BootstrapperBuilder.Products Property. This nothing talks to me.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562%28v=vs.100%29.aspx  MSDN has documentation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really return a single object in the sense you are assuming.  What it returns is a "Query", (an object that implements `IQueryable<Product>`), that has the capacity to iterate through, and return a set of objects (of type `Product`) when the calling code calls `foreach` on it. It doesn't actually process the query *until* the calling code calls `foreach`.
 You can think of it (the return object) as a *set of instructions* as to how to process, slice, dice and filter the set of objects you started with (`repository.Products`) and generate a new set of objects from that initial set.
The code doesn't actually generate this new set until something calls `foreach` on it.  If you want this new set to actually be constructed (so you can manipulate it or iterate through it yourself), then you can call `ToList()` on it as described by @MotoSV.

```
List<Product> products = repository.Products
                    .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                    .Take(PageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: Can I found this object "Query" in MSDN to read more about it. So I understand that this object represent the queries of products which I typed and it actually selects and goes to database and returns some values when and only foreach is invoked over it ?

Comment: No "Query" is just a term I used.  And it does not go to the database, it just processes the objects in the `repository.Products; collection.

Comment: So in fact it runs queries to table when foreach is called ?

Comment: Yes, it runs *the* query, (defined by the LINQ expression), against the collection the Linq expression is called on, in your case, against `repository.Products`

Answer (score 3):

It returns an `IQueryable` of type `Products` to a collection of `Product` instances. If you want to see the contents of `products`, then put a breakpoint on the LINQ statement, step over that line and then hover over the `products` variable to see it's contents.

Note, you may have to do a `ToList()` at the end of the LINQ statement in order to see the results as they may not yet be returned from your repository. Check if the `Take` methods "eager" loads the results. If your repository is a collection of objects, then a `ToList` won't be required, but if you are accessing a database, i.e. through Entity Framework, then it will be.